# C memcpy crashing at run time

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct, memcpy

i have this issue.
Whenever i try to call StorageStore it crashes on run time.
I have no idea how to fix it.
I have tried googling but iam kinda inexperienced about pointers.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: i compile with gcc -Ofast

```
uint8_t Storage[256];

typedef struct _QCPU {
    uint8_t pc; // 1
    uint8_t *regs; // 7
    uint8_t *dCache; // 8 (32)
    uint8_t *iCache; // 8 (32)
    uint8_t **port_table; // 8 (8)
    void *str_load; // 8 (1)
    void *str_store; // 8 (1)
    struct Flags flags;
} QCPU;

void StorageStore(QCPU *CPU, uint8_t Addr)
{
    memcpy(Storage+(Addr & 0xE0), CPU->dCache, 32);
}

QCPU* init()
{
    return (QCPU*) malloc(sizeof(QCPU)); // Return Allocated Pointer To QCPU
}

int main()
{
    QCPU *cpu = init();
    cpu->dCache[3] = 5;
    StorageStore(cpu, 5);
    free(cpu);
}
```

Comment: Pointers are not arrays.

Comment: The line `cpu->dCache[3] = 5;` dereferences the uninitialised pointer `cpu->dCache` and then writes to the random address found a `5`.

Comment: `CPU->dCache` is an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: You may find https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html helpful.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: A pointer is an index (or address) of a memory cell, if you think of memory as a 1D array of cells. If you have a pointer to a string, for example, than you have an index of the memory cell, whe the first character of the string is stored. Next characters follow. You really need to study it first a bit, so that you know exactly what you're doing and what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling about what uninitialised pointer is
i realized my issue

thank you alk, Paul Hankin and Jiri Volejnik for your answers

i added these line to fix it

```
QCPU* init()
{
    QCPU* r = malloc(sizeof(QCPU)); // Allocated Pointer To QCPU
    r->dCache = malloc(32);
    r->iCache = malloc(32);
    r->port_table = malloc(8);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: If it's always 32, you could also write `uint8_t dCache[32];` in the structure.